# Internet Connection Check UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView that loads a PDF document, like this:

```
NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.site.com/myPDF.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl];

// Clear Cache, to insure prompt update of PDF
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:myRequest];
[myWebView loadRequest:myRequest];
```

When my internet connection is off, i get nothing. Just a blank UIView. Is there any way i can detect when there is not internet connection, or check if the URLContents is empty? I am trying to call a method `-(void)showErrorText` to show text in the center screen. How would i do this? (I got the method complete, just not the internet check). THANKS.

Comment: You could run a timer based Reachability test on a background thread, maybe ?

Comment: Why on a timer? Would that not be wasteful of Data?

Comment: I'm not saying get/download data. Simply use the Reachability class to check on a specified interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to set the delegate of the webView to self and implements the `webView:didFailLoadWithError` and the others delagate methods tout have more details.